# Find integral of $f:D\to \mathbb{C}$ where $f$ is a branch of square root with $f(1)=-1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Let $C$ be the intersection of the circle of raidus $2$ with the set $\{x+iy:y\geq 0\}$ with start and end point $2,-2$ respectively and let $D=\{re^{i\theta}:r>0, \theta\in(-\pi/2,3\pi/2)\}$

> Let $f:D\to \mathbb{C}$ be a branch of square root with $f(1)=-1$, find $\int_C f(z)dz$

So I believe I can find the integral of the square root function normally by substituting $z=2e^{it}$ and then taking the integral of $\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^\pi e^{1/2 it}ie^{it}dt$ to get $F(z)=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}(e^{\frac{9}{4}\pi i}+e^{\frac{1}{4}\pi i})$

Im not sure what to do with the fact that $f$ is a branch of the square root

Comment: What expression did you take for $f(z)$? Does this expression have $f(1) = -1$? (or equivalently; does this have $f(2) = - \sqrt{2}$ ?) If not then you have not used the correct branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(re^{i\theta}) = -\sqrt{r} e^{(\frac{\theta}{2})i}$ for $\theta\in[0, 2\pi)$.

How do we know this is the branch we want? Well, first it's easy to check that $f(z)^2=z$, so it's indeed a square-root function, and it's clearly continuous (so it falls into one branch instead of jumping between branches), finally $f(1) = f(1\cdot e^{0\cdot i}) = -1$.

The semi-circle can be parametrized by $\gamma(\theta) = 2e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta\in [0, \pi]$. Hence $$\int_D f(z)dz = \int_{\theta = 0}^\pi -\sqrt{2} e^{(\frac{\theta}{2})i}d(2e^{i\theta})$$

Here is another way to do it. The branch can be continuously extended to the closed upper half plane (but not analytically), therefore we can apply the Cauchy–Goursat theorem to get $\int_{D\cup[-2, 2]}f(z)dz=0$, hence $$\int_D f(z)dz = -\int_{[-2,2]} f(z)dz=-(\int_{-2}^0 f(z)dz+\int_{0}^2f(z)dz)$$ By continuity of $f$, if $f(1)=-1$, then $f(r)=-\sqrt{r}$ for real $r\ge 0$, and $f(-r) = -i\sqrt{|r|}$ for $r<0$. So the answer is simply $$\int_Df(z)dz = \int_{-2}^0 i\sqrt{|r|}dr + \int_0^2 \sqrt{r}dr=(1+i)\int_0^2\sqrt{r}dr$$

Comment: So just to clarify, $D$ gives me my function is holomorphic on $C$ because the branch cut is at $-\pi/2$. And then $f(1)=-1$ is used to determine whether to take the positive or negative square root?

Comment: Almost. You can cut the branch in many different places on the plane, not necessarily along (lower part of) the $y$-axis, as long as it doesn't separate $D$ into two pieces. We can only discuss positive/negative when the square-root is real, but it's true that if we pick positive/negative ones on the real line, we have fixed the whole branch on the plane (except where we cut). But these are just conceptual issues that won't affect the calculation.